# How to check if user is logged in at custom page in Opencart

Tags: php, content-management-system, opencart

I have a custom page in Opencart. In this page I am using PHP and Javascript based text editor. Now I need to check if user is logged in so that some more options are displayed. I had searched on Google but I did't find anything.

Comment: you mean in admin page or frontend ?

Comment: Check this link.Here i am working.[link]http://www.musicjee.com/project/index.php?route=information/editor).

Comment: @user3176663, This is not exactly a general programming question and should be asked on http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/77558/opencart instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Your controller (of that custom page) You can do this:

```
if($this->customer->isLogged()) {
    echo "Customer is logged in and his ID is " . $this->customer->isLogged();
} else {
    echo "Customer is not logged in";
}
```

This assumes that the custom page is within frontend and by user You actually mean **customer** (this assumption was done just because in backend every user has to be logged in prior to display any page).

Comment: Is there a cleaner way to do with in tpl files, using $logged is not accurate

Comment: If you need this for *OC 2.0>* then there is no clearer way. TBH I do not see anything *unclear* in this solution. If you need it for *OC 2.0<* it might have changed a little, I'm not working with *OC 2.0<* anymore...

Comment: For OC 2.0 > it appears they send $logged variable to the views to identify if the user is logged or not.